# SQL Pivot Data w/o Aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is structured like so:

```
ID | Type | PrimaryInd | SecondaryInd | TertiaryInd
---------------------------------------------------
12 | Boat |     0      |      1       |     0  
12 | Auto |     1      |      1       |     1
12 | Home |     1      |      0       |     1
```

And I am trying to get the results for each ID to be on one row like so:

```
ID | BoatPrimaryInd | BoatSecondaryInd | BoatTertiaryInd | AutoPrimaryInd | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12 |       0        |        1         |        0        |       1        | ...
```

I currently have my query set up like this using a CASE and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   MIN(CASE WHEN Type = 'Boat' THEN PrimaryInd+0 END) AS BoatPrimaryInd,
   ...
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

Is this the most effecient way of doing this? I tried looking into PIVOT tables but I'm not sure that's what I need since I don't have anything to aggregate here...

Comment: Your way is fine.

Comment: The conditional aggregation (the way you have it) or pivot would work. The latter is usually trickier for folks and thus, conditional aggregation is an easy workaround when the values are static and there aren't that many of them. What I mean is if you had 500 types, you probably don't want to write 500 `case` expressions.

Comment: And to elaborate, with Pivot you'd have to have multiple (nested) pivots here so it'd get uglier.

Comment: @scsimon You say ugly... I say pretty  :)

Comment: Ha yes, for static values or just a few for sure.

Comment: And conditional aggregation is slightly faster most of the time than PIVOT. Jeff Moden wrote about that [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/). The differences in performance are not as pronounced in recent years though because processors have gotten so much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PIVOT in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select A.ID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat([Type],'PrimaryInd')  ,[PrimaryInd]  )
                             ,(concat([Type],'SecondaryInd'),[SecondaryInd])
                             ,(concat([Type],'TertiaryInd') ,[TertiaryInd] )
                     )B(Item,Value)
        ) src
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in (
                                [BoatPrimaryInd],
                                [BoatSecondaryInd],
                                [BoatTertiaryInd],
                                [AutoPrimaryInd],
                                [AutoSecondaryInd],
                                [AutoTertiaryInd],
                                [HomePrimaryInd],
                                [HomeSecondaryInd],
                                [HomeTertiaryInd]
                                ) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]